# Should I quit my job if the company needs me more than ever?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, quitting, teamwork

I am a software and database developer in a small team. We used to be four of us in the team (four and my boss).

I had plans to find another job at the beginning of 2015, I'm thinking about this since May or Jun of this year.

The thing is that, two of my co-workers went out of the company in the lapse of May to now, the work is not balanced now, and I want to keep the plan of find another job but if I move to another job, there will be just one developer in the team.

My boss is looking for new developers to hire, but for my experience about the company, takes too long to hire.

Should I stay until the team goes back to 3 - 4 developers or should I keep my plans for 2015 of find another job?

Comment: not really enough information to answer it. For starters, why are you looking to leave in 2015? Money? Unhappy? Want new experiences?

Comment: All what you mention really.

Comment: The question will probably get closed because it's an considered "unanswerable" but I'll tell you what I would tell anyone. You have to do what's best for you. Friendship is friendship but business is business. Never ever let the needs of the business supersede your own needs. You owe them an honest day's work for an honest day's pay but you don't owe them your life.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My boss is looking for new developers to hire, but for my experience about the company, takes too long to hire.

I've been in a very similar situation just lately. It's great that you feel concern for your current company, but in the end, you should look at your own interests first of all, as the company is doing the same (supposedly). If your boss knows since May that they need new developers and still hasn't hired anyone, that's your problem only inasmuch as it's keeping your workload high too; however, the problem is theirs to solve, not yours.

I suggest either of these two options:

- accept a better job offer when you get one according to your original plan, or
- talk to your boss about this situation and offer a deal that you stay till, say, Spring 2015 to give them more time to fill up the vacancies, in exchange for extra compensation (higher pay, bonus, ...). If your workload is higher and you have more responsibilities due to your boss not having arranged new team members to help you, it's only fair for the company to give back more in exchange. Who knows, that may even help motivate them to get new hires faster?

Comment: Thanks for your time for answering, I will end up by taking one of the two options you provide. God bless you bro.

Answer (score 3):

Whether your company needs you or not should be irrelevant in your considerations for leaving. It should only be relevant in terms of remuneration (although, I wouldn't exactly go in and say "hey, you need me so pay me more or I walk").

Unless whatever reason(s) you had for deciding to leave before have gone away, you should probably still think about leaving.

I realise that you're probably concerned over bridge-burning (and I have been in a similar situation), and leaving your current organisation at a time of need will cause some ill-will with your boss and/or employer. However, if you have already started to plan to leave in the next year, you will likely end up resenting that you "had" to stay and this will end up being worse for you and everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

You are not a social worker and neither is your company a social work organization.

Look out for yourself and let your company's management solve their own problems. They are old enough to take care of themselves and if they need someone, the worst that happens to them is that they pay extra to get that person. Not the end of the world if that happens.